# Booting a 2-partition Windows 10 installation from GRUB2 command-line

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, gpt, mbr

I'm using a GRUB2 prompt after booting from a Linux rescue USB flash drive (finnix-123) - trying to boot my Windows 10. It is on an SSD with MBR rather than GPT, with two partitions: one of about 100 MB, the other filling the rest of the disk. Both partitions are NTFS. The second partition is "hibernated". I can't boot that SSD directly, probably because my new computer's UEFI doesn't support booting from MBR disks (although I'm not 100% certain that's the reason).

So, I tried the instructions suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/592938/34868):

```
insmod part_msdos
insmod chain
set root='(hd1,msdos1)'
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

(my system has two disks, hd0 which is the flash drive, and hd1 which is the SSD I want to boot.)

but the last command results in an error about the file not being found.

Can I still boot my Windows somehow via my grub2 prompt? If not - can I boot it some other way without writing to the disk?

Comment: You posted a UEFI type entry as bootmfgfw.efi is for UEFI Windows. That would be on a gpt drive (hd0,gpt1 or similar). Windows in BIOS mode boots from the boot folder probably your first partition. But with BIOS/MBR boot files can be in main partition. these are the BIOS boot files. /bootmgr /Boot/BCD. If Windows hibernated, you will not be able to boot from Linux. Best just to install a Windows boot loader into MBR of that drive & boot directly. New systems now are UEFI only. Lenovo announced all 2020 products will be UEFI only (UEFI Class 3 or no CSM).

Comment: @oldfred: Can you expand this into an answer, including information/lkibks on how you suggest I install the boot loader? I was assuming one was already installed, given how Windows was the only thing ever to be installed on that disk.

Comment: I would then expect BIOS boot loader is in MBR. You have to change system to boot in BIOS mode or CSM/legacy. CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode, only available with secure boot off. You may also need f8 for Windows repair console. Typically you need a Windows repair/recovery flash drive for the version you are trying to boot to make repairs. If just boot loader in MBR, you can from Linux install the syslinux boot loader, but I suspect other issues, so best to use Windows repair tools.